Unity require me to assigned Variable even though I dont need to assign it
I make a weapon Recoil Script in my own 3rd person shooter game. Since I don't want the AI to also generate recoil
public class WeaponRecoil : MonoBehaviour
{
    [HideInInspector]
    public PlayerAim playerAiming;

    [HideInInspector]
    public CinemachineImpulseSource cameraShake;

    [HideInInspector]
    public Animator rigController;

    public Vector2[] recoilPattern;
    public float duration;

    float verticalRecoil;
    float horizontalRecoil;
    float time;
    int index;
    int recoilLayerIndex = -1;

    void Awake()
    {
        cameraShake = GetComponent<CinemachineImpulseSource>();
    }

    void Start()
    {
        if (rigController)
        {
            recoilLayerIndex = rigController.GetLayerIndex("Recoil Layer");
        }
    }

    int NextIndex(int _index)
    {
        return (_index + 1) % recoilPattern.Length;
    }

    public void Reset()
    {
        index = 0;
    }

    public void GenerateRecoil(string _weaponName)
    {
            time = duration;

            cameraShake.GenerateImpulse(Camera.main.transform.forward);

            horizontalRecoil = recoilPattern[index].x;
            verticalRecoil = recoilPattern[index].y;

            index = NextIndex(index);

            rigController?.Play("Weapon_Anim_Recoil_" + _weaponName, 1, 0.0f);
        
            
    }

    void Update()
    {
        if (time > 0)
        {
            playerAiming.yAxis.Value -= ((verticalRecoil / 10) * Time.deltaTime) / duration;
            playerAiming.xAxis.Value -= ((horizontalRecoil / 10) * Time.deltaTime) / duration;
            time -= Time.deltaTime;
        }
    }
}

Whenever I fire using a gun, a Bullet Script will execute function
recoil.GenerateRecoil();

Meanwhile I only assigned the rigController variable in a script that is exclusive to the player
weapon.recoil.rigController = rigController;

P.S. the weapon variable is the bullet script.
Even though I already use
if (rigController)

to check if the rigController is null(for the AI it should be null) and
rigController?.Play("Weapon_Anim_Recoil_" + _weaponName, 1, 0.0f);

the Debug log still needs me to assign rigController when my AI try to access it.
I want the script to be only accessible to the player, and for AI it will just skip it.

rigController?.Play() is wrong for unity objects/components. You have to use if(rigController) rigController.Play(). I prefer if(rigController != null) rigController.Play() as it makes clear you are using Unity's overriden == operator. Perhaps write a guard clause on your GenerateRecoil function: if(rigController == null) return; as the first statement. This makes it really clear the function should do nothing if the animator is null.

That fixed my problem, thank you very much
